# update images gallery using csv file in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, woocommerce

I have an issue I need to update the gallery images of my products on my WordPress store, this store doesn't use woocommerce but a plugin called alidropship,I want to use a CSV file that had the IDs of products and images but when I use wp all import plugin to update the images by the csv file, gallery images don’t go to the gallery
Because the gallery is a custom field from alidropship plugin, the plugin I used to import products

even if the products uploaded but doesn’t displayed, because the gallery is not like WooCommerce gallery and I don’t know how to update these images with a CSV file using wp all import plugin, I can't do it manually because I have a lot of produts

Alidropship plugin has changed the gallery field, that’s what the products don’t appear when I have used WP all import plugin to update products